# when i import library as a module in android studio, i came across red at Class

Tags: java, android

[image]

I imported library as a module in Android studio.
But, I can't use this library.
how should I do?

Comment: Show the app *build.gradle** file. And what steps did you tale in importing the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is shortcut for android studio to external library to your product.

1. `ctrl + Alt + Shift + s`
2. You will see a dialog, and click on Dependencies
3. Click on `+` to add or `-` to remove
4. Sync your build.gradle

Simple

Answer (score 2):

just add this line in dependencies of your app level gradle file

```
compile project('module folder name')
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a **libs** folder in package. The **libs** folder should be in **ProjectName > app**. Add your file inside the libs folder, right click on it and select **Add as library**.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File > **Project structure** > Click on "**app**" from menu of left side > Click on **dependencies** from top of menu options  > Click on " **+** "> Choose the option "**Module Dependency**" , it will give you option of your library, click on that library option , Click on **OK**, your library will be added as a module.and you can see it in your app level gradle file